# Swift How can I sort a list of clothing sizes (e.g. XL, S, 2XL, XXS)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I've an array of dictionary with something like this:

```
[["XL":956], ["M":1010], ["S":998], ["L":955], ["XXL":921], ["XS":1041], ["30":45], ["28":41], ["32":46], ["26":35], ["34":50], ["One Size":1]]
```

**How do I sort it so that it is in this order?**

```
[["XS":1041], ["S":998], ["M":1010], ["L":955], ["XL":956], ["XXL":921], ["26":35], ["28":41], ["30":45], ["32":46], ["34":50], ["One Size":1]]
```

*Note that every size is not always present, it's dynamic*

Comment: sorry it's actually array of dictionary

Comment: Rather than having an array of one element dictionaries you would be better of using a struct in the array instead. The code would be easier to read and you could add business logic and/or other properties ti the struct if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference `array` that contains the alphabetical sizes in sorted order.

Now, `sort` the `array` based on reference `array`, i.e.

```
let data = [["XL":956], ["M":1010], ["S":998], ["L":955], ["XXL":921], ["XS":1041], ["30":45], ["28":41], ["32":46], ["26":35], ["34":50], ["One Size":1]]

let ref = ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"]

let result = data.sorted { (val1, val2) -> Bool in
    if let key1 = val1.first?.key, let key2 = val2.first?.key {
        if let x = Int(key1), let y = Int(key2) {
            return x < y
        } else if let x = ref.firstIndex(of: key1), let y = ref.firstIndex(of: key2) {
            return x < y
        } else {
            return ref.firstIndex(of: key1) != nil
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: You *can* sort a dictionary (the result is an array of key/value tuples). The first map is not needed.

Comment: @MartinR The question was different earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident about knowing all of your size strings, and so happy to force unwrap, you can do it in a one-liner.

```
let order = ["XS", "S", "M", "L",  "XL",  "XXL", "26", "28", "30", "32", "34", "One Size"]

let sorted = sizes.sorted{order.firstIndex(of: $0.first!.key)! < order.firstIndex(of: $1.first!.key)!}
```

Depending on where you are going to use this, the better option would be to unwrap the optionals safely in case of bad data! :-)